# The Apache Nifi state is not persisted to zookeeper

Tags: state, apache-nifi, apache-zookeeper

According to the official [Nifi documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#state_management), the state allows Nifi processors to "*resume from the place where it left off after NiFi is restarted. Additionally, it allows for a Processor to **store some piece of information** so that the Processor can access that information from all of the different nodes in the cluster*".

If my understanding is good, when we configure a zookeeper Provider, the state will not be persisted locally, instead, the data will be sent to zookeeper.

I've explored the zookeeper znodes and could not find any data related to the state, all I can find are the informations about the Coordinator and Primary nodes. However, the local state directory is still filled.

The configuration is very simple, I've 3 external ZK nodes and 3 Nifi instances.

Here is an exerpt of the nifi.properties file:

```
nifi.cluster.is.node=true
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=zk-node1:2181,zk-node2:2181,zk-node3:2181
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=false
nifi.state.management.provider.cluster=zk-provider
```

And here is an exerpt of the state-management.xml file:

```
<cluster-provider>
        <id>zk-provider</id>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.controller.state.providers.zookeeper.ZooKeeperStateProvider</class>
        <property name="Connect String">zk-node1:2181,zk-node2:2181,zk-node3:2181</property>
        <property name="Root Node">/nifi</property>
        <property name="Session Timeout">10 seconds</property>
        <property name="Access Control">Open</property>
    </cluster-provider>
```

When I try to ls the Zookeeper, I can see only 2 znodes: "components" but this znode is empty and the "leaders" zonde which contain some data about the Nifi Coordinator and Primary Nodes.

Also, when I explore the transactions logs, even after using some load balanced connections, I cannot find anything related to the Nifi State.

Could somebody explain what data goes the Zookeeper and why the local state directory is still filled even if we configure the zk provider ?

Thanks.

Comment: Zk state is not universal, each processor or service would have to implement using zk for stateful operations. Also, NiFi uses local h2 databases for data processing state management.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the processor, some cases it would never make sense to store cluster wide state because it could never be picked up by another node. For example, ListFile tracking from a local directory, another node cannot access the same directory so storing this state in ZK is not helpful.

There is always a local state provider in a write-ahead-log in the state directory, and it is up to the processor to say whether it should be cluster or local state when storing it.

The documentation for each processor should say how the state is stored. For example, from ListFile:

```
@Stateful(scopes = {Scope.LOCAL, Scope.CLUSTER}, description = "After performing a listing of files, the timestamp of the newest file is stored. "
    + "This allows the Processor to list only files that have been added or modified after "
    + "this date the next time that the Processor is run. Whether the state is stored with a Local or Cluster scope depends on the value of the "
    + "<Input Directory Location> property.")
```

If Input Directory Location is "remote" then it will use cluster state, otherwise local state.